# Fixpoint-Overflow-Traps for int16_t and int8_t

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

I have a complicated program with fixed-point arithmetic.

It seems that there are occasional overflows.

To find them I have set the flag `-ftrapv`. This seems to work only with `int32_t`. Is that correct?

Is there a way to achieve the same behavior with `int16_t` and `int8_t`?

Here is my test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    int8_t int8 = 127;
    int8 += 1;
    printf("int8: %d\n",int8);

    int16_t int16 = 32767;
    int16 += 1;
    printf("int16: %d\n",int16);

    int32_t int32 = 2147483647;
    int32 += 1;
    printf("int32: %d\n",int32);
}
```

I compile with:

```
rm a.out; gcc -ftrapv main.c && ./a.out
```

and get:

```
int8: -128
int16: -32768
Aborted
```

My compiler version is `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609`.

Note: Some of the answers refer to a test program that I have incorrectly written before.

Comment: I don't think your results are correct, because types smaller than int will always be promoted to int, so those int8 and int16 operations don't overflow

Comment: @ Lưu Vĩnh Phúc: Yes, see also Lundin's answer

Comment: Voting to close this since the question has changed and it now invalidates posted answers.

Answer (score 7):

I have no idea what you are trying to do.

- The maximum value a `int8_t` can hold is 127 and ***not*** 255.
- The maximum value a `int16_t` is 32767 and ***not***  65535.
- The maximum value a `int32_t` can hold is indeed 2147483647.

So this is what your code does:

- `int8_t int8 = 255;` Assign the value 255 to a variable that can hold a maximum of 127. It won't fit, invoke implicit conversion in some implementation-defined manner. Most likely you end up with the value -1. This is an implicit lvalue conversion and no signed integer overflow.
- `printf("int8: %d\n",int8 + 1);` Print the result of `-1 + 1`. It is `0`. No overflow anywhere.
- The very same thing happens with the 16 bit variable, implicit conversion, end up with value -1, print a 0.
- `int32_t int32 = 2147483647;` This line is different from the other two, as you actually set the int32 to the maximum value it can contain. If you take `+1` on that, you do get a signed integer overflow which invokes undefined behavior.

On top of that, the two smaller integer types *can't* overflow upon the addition, even if that was what your code was doing (which it doesn't). Both operands would get integer promoted to type `int` - there would be no overflow. See [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules) for a detailed explanation about how this works.

Comment: You're right! It's an artifact. I started with uint8_t and uint16_t.

Comment: The output is than 128, 32768, Aborted

Answer (score 5):

I don't think so, since because of C's default integer promotion rules, the arithmetic really doesn't happen as the smaller types.

For instance (from the C11 draft, §5.1.2.3 11):

> EXAMPLE 2
>   In executing the fragment
>
> ```
> char c1, c2;
> /* ... */
> c1 = c1 + c2;
> ```
>
> the "integer promotions" require that the abstract machine promote the
>   value of each variable to `int` size and then add the two `int`s and 
>   truncate the sum.

This is frequently the cause of confusion in code like:

```
uint8_t x;

x = get_some_byte();
x |= 1;
```

The last line is really the equivalent of:

```
x = x | 1;
```

and the right-hand side will be promoted to `int`, so the assignment "back" to `uint8_t` risks truncating which some tools warn you about.

Comment: Even if there was no implicit promotion of the operands, there would be no overflow, because `-1 + 1` is well-defined. The problem isn't so much the implicit promotion, but rather the OP assigning the wrong values to the variables.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the following minimally invasive method for myself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef INTOF_CHECK
#define INTOF_ERROR (printf("line %d: loss of bits\n", __LINE__) & 0)
#define i8(v) ((v) > 127 || (v) < -127 ? INTOF_ERROR : (v))
#define i16(v) ((v) > 32767 || (v) < -32768 ? INTOF_ERROR : (v))
#else
#define i8(v) (v)
#define i16(v) (v)
#endif

int main(void)
{  
    int8_t int8 = i8(127);
    printf("int8: %d\n",i8(int8 + 1));

    int16_t int16 = i16(32767);
    printf("int16: %d\n",i16(int16 + 1));
}
```

Compile with:

```
rm -f a.out; gcc main.c -DINTOF_CHECK && ./a.out
```

The output is:

```
line 16: loss of bits
int8: 0
line 19: loss of bits
int16: 0
```